# Change design of catalog/product options in Magento admin

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

Need help with locating a particular piece of code in Magento.

Based on screenshot below, I need to change the "Attribute 1" select box to, say, list of radios. Or, I just want to be able to make this particular select box red or whatever.

But after couple of hours of searching, I still can't find the code, which stands for this particular part of view.

Can anyone give a hint where to look for this code ?

[image: Magento admin catalog/product design]

Comment: Ok, I found the view, which I needed in \app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\catalog\form\renderer\fieldset .

Answer (score 0):

If you look in `Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes` you will see all existing attributes, you can't change the type of an existing attribute but you can create a new attribute and make it a radio selection or dropdown etc..

Once you have created a new attribute you will then need to add it in to an attribute set ( `Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attribute set)`. You can create a new tab (e.g. 'Some tab') by creating a new group and adding your newly created attribute in to that.

Comment: Instead of radio, dropdown, etc.., which are offered while creating new attribute, I need a custom solution, where the categories tree is shown instead of the dropdown, like it is in Catalog -> Product -> Cattegories, only instead of checkboxes, there must be radio buttons. Therefore, it can't be done without coding. But I can't find the place where to code ...